# Change axis title position in {ggplot2}

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, axis, title

The axis titles are normally centered over the axis themselves. How can I change the positions? For example, I want my y-axis title to be on top of the y-axis, and the x-axis title to be on the right of the x-axis. Does anybody know how to do it in R with `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out. So, for the y-axis, you should set `axis.title = element_text(hjust = 1)`  to be on top, and for the x-axis `axis.title = element_text(vjust = 1)` to be on the right (which sounds pretty unintuitive to me, given the y-axis is the vertical one). All inside theme(), this is. So, to conclude:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point() +
theme(axis.title = element_text(vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: We just need `hjust = 1`